# I want to add one extra field to my URLs, I'm using Rewrite functions but it doesn't work

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I think my question isn't in the right way, I just ask it. I want this routings for my wordpress site (for example in Custom PostType Archive page):

```
example.com/VALUE          =>  example.com/?mykey=VALUE
example.com/a/VALUE        =>  example.com/a/?mykey=VALUE
example.com/a/b/VALUE      =>  example.com/a/b/?mykey=VALUE
example.com/a/b/.../VALUE  =>  example.com/a/b/.../?mykey=VALUE
```

I searched for it, I read many articles and answers but they didn't work, or maybe I couldn't make them work! Most of the answers were how to use Rewrite API, add_rewrite_rule(), add_rewrite_endpoint() and so on...

I really need this, I really need a working example please, thank you.

Comment: Post your code and let us know what didn't worked. hard to help without code

Comment: @Sisir I don't even know how to use the Rewrite functions :(